# xslt, javascript and unescaped html entities

Tags: javascript, xslt, html-entities

i have a tiny little problem with xslt, js and html entities, eg. within a template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:value-of select="/some/node"/>
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; 5; i++) {
        //            ^^^ js error
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:value-of select="/some/node"/>
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //            ^ xslt error
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:value-of select="/some/node"/>
    // <![CDATA[
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //            ^ becomes &lt;
    }
    // ]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:value-of select="/some/node"/>
    for (var i = 0; i <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('&lt;')"/> 5; i++) {
        // works of course
    }
</script>
```

does anyone have an idea where my problem could come from? i always thought the xslt processor would leave the content of a <script/> element unescaped when using the html output method ...

i run libxslt2 version 1.1.24 on OSX which was installed using macportsports ...

Comment: (answer deleted as no longer relevant)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ok. long story, short answer:

it seems that with **some libxslt versions** the xslt processor leaves the content of a <script/> element unescaped when using the html output method, **with others
not** ... therefore the following is recommended:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:value-of select="/some/node"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
        // ^ does the trick ...
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //            ^ works
        }
    </xsl:text>
</script>
```

Comment: HEY! You saved my life. No, at least a couple of hours! Thanks.

Comment: Gidday there, this Question's a bit old now but if you get this, perhaps you can help with my Q? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411376/xslt-disable-output-escaping-not-holding-across-two-diff-servers  Its the same problem, but your solution works on my localhost, but not my hosted server. They appear to have the same configuration :/

Comment: This does not work in my case. I get the XSLT error `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.` and it points to the line with the `<`

Answer (score 4):

> i always thought the xslt processor would leave the content of a script element unescaped when using the html output method

You are correct: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method

```
The html output method should not perform escaping for the content of the script and style elements.
For example, a literal result element written in the stylesheet as
    <script>if (a &lt; b) foo()</script>
or
    <script><![CDATA[if (a < b) foo()]]></script>
should be output as
    <script>if (a < b) foo()</script>
```

If your XSLT processor is doing otherwise, it's a bug.

However, in any case it's a good idea to avoid '<' and '&' in embedded scripts, and an even better idea to kick all the code out into a linked .js file.

Comment: If XSLT is generating the variable JS script, a linked js file isn't always a possibility and avoiding < and & isn't going to be realistic

Comment: looks like a bug then ... i'll try to narrow it down the best i can an submit the bug report ... cheerz for your answer ...

Answer (score 1):

The `CDATA` blocks should have worked; they always have for me. What's your `disable-output-escaping` value?

UPDATE:
Using Xalan, with `disable-output-escaping` on its default, which I'm pretty sure is `no`, I have the following in my working XSL files:

- No `CDATA` block:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i `&lt;` foo.length; i++) {
  …
  }
  ```
- `CDATA` block:

  ```
  <![CDATA[

  for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) { … }

  ]]>
  ```

Comment: do you mean using the following:

    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('&amp;')"/>

works, but this isn't how is should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the double slash before the CDATA of your third solution

Answer (score 0):

If the `xsl:output` method is html, the CDATA section would work. If the `xsl:output` method is xml, the < and > signs would still be converted.

To get around this problem, you may define the script element to not behave this way using the xsl:output element. you can also force the method of the output using xml or html

```
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script" />
...
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
  for (var i = 0; i &lt; foo.length; i++) { … }
]]>
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work in my case, what I get in the output is `&amp;lt;`, and my output type is `html`