# If greater than javascript into XSLT doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have javascript code into xslt which should check image dimension. If width is greater than height to rotate img.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var a = 3;
    var b = 1;
    if (a > b) {
      document.getElementById("img1").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
    }  
 </script>
```

I tried:

```
1) &gt;

2) <![CDATA[ --code --]]>

3) disable-output-escaping="yes"
```

But nothing works. In console see an error message 
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `&gt;` in your XSLT but set

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

so that it is serialized as `>`;

**See also**

- [How to include javaScript file in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7444317/290085)
- [xslt, javascript and unescaped html entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/435005/290085)

Comment: I have already selected one of your links as a dupe. I think you could have done the same

Comment: @mplungjan: At the time of your comment preceding your VTC, I'd already posted this answer without the "See also"  links.  I thought your duplicate link was good, so I added it and another too, all within initial 4 minutes.  No disrespect intended.

Comment: @kjhughes I saw that link "xslt, javascript and unescaped html entities" before and tried everything but it doesn`t work for me.
even output as html.

Comment: @BladeRunner: Are you trying to run your XSLT in the browser, or does your XSLT generate HTML on the server (or offline, batch), which is then sent to the browser?

Comment: @kjhughes none taken

Comment: @kjhughes I tested it with C# program which generates from XSLT -> HTML, and I check this HTML file in the browser.
What worries me that even when I use " if (a > b)" XSLT interpreter doesn`t show me an error. And in Browser I see already a formatted symbol.

Comment: So, all's working when you use `>` directly then?   BTW, `>` can be used directly in more contexts than `<` can.   See [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents/46637835#46637835)